# Ajax requests growing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my website, I have a button created dynamically.
When someone click in that button (I'm processing the "click" event with "livequery"), the
script does an ajax request, but if I click again, instead of 1 request, now there are 2
requests at the same time, and if I click again, 3 request, and so on.
Anybody has an idea about what is going on?
My code is like this ( I didn't put } and }); to close my commands ):

```
$('#generate').livequery('click',function(){
                    //Make the formatBox
                    $( "#formatBox" ).dialog({
                            height: 200,
                            width: 500,
                            resizable: false,
                            modal: true
                    });
                    $('#generateWithSpecificFormat').livequery('click',function(){
                            $( "#formatBox:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

                            //Make the request to CGI
                            $.ajax({
                                    url: '../../cgi-bin/list.py',
                                    type: 'POST',
```

Thanks!

Comment: please complete what is `$('#generate').livequery()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is this `$('#generateWithSpecificFormat').livequery('click',function(){})`. You don't have to put it inside `$('#generate').livequery('click',function(){})`. Put that outside and everything *should* work fine.